# JavaScript events and bubbling

Tags: javascript, dom-events, event-bubbling

I have the following (simplified) markup code:

```
<div id="container">
    <div data-value="1">
        <span>Click me 1</span>
    </div>
    <div data-value="2">
        <span>Click me 2</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="messages"></div>
```

I want to take advantage of bubbling by attaching an event listener only on the `#container`, and get the clicked children's `data-value`.

```
document.getElementById('container').addEventListener('click', function(e){
    document.getElementById('messages').innerHTML = 'you clicked ' + e.target.dataset.value;
}, false);
```

Everything works fine if the clicked area is the `div` area (in red in the fiddle). How can I get the `data-value` also when the click comes from a children of the div (e.g. click on a blue span) with the data value without changing the event listener?

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hgLagy31/1/

Comment: `e.target.parentNode.dataset.value;` - if you click the span.

Comment: right, but this is just an example, the markup structure inside the divs with data-value could change - with more (grand)children also

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`e.target` is the element the user clicked, it is showing `undefined` since the `<span>` does not have a `data-value` attribute. You could go up the tree and find the nearest ancestor that does contain a `data-value`.

```js
document.getElementById('container').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  // Find nearest ancestor with data-value defined
  var node = e.target;
  while (!node.dataset.value) {
    node = node.parentNode;
  }
  document.getElementById('messages').innerHTML =
    'you clicked ' + node.dataset.value;
}, false);
```

```css
#container > div {
  background: red;
}
#container > div > span {
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div data-value="1">
    <span>Click me 1</span>
  </div>
  <div data-value="2">
    <span>Click me 2</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="messages"></div>
```

To make this more robust, you could check whether `node` is `undefined` before continuing in the `while` loop and exit if so:

```
while (!node.dataset || !node.dataset.value) {
  node = node.parentNode;
  if (!node) {
    document.getElementById('messages').innerHTML =
        'Could not find data-value';
    return;
  }
}
```

```js
document.getElementById('container').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  // Find nearest ancestor with data-value defined
  var node = e.target;
  while (!node.dataset || !node.dataset.value) {
    node = node.parentNode;
    if (!node) {
      document.getElementById('messages').innerHTML = 'Could not find data-value';
      return;
    }
  }
  document.getElementById('messages').innerHTML =
    'you clicked ' + node.dataset.value;
}, false);
```

```css
#container > div {
  background: red;
}
#container > div > span {
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div data-value="1">
    <span>Click me 1</span>
  </div>
  <div data-value="2">
    <span>Click me 2</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>Click me 3</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="messages"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you asked for a solution that doesn't involve changing the event listener...

```
#container > div > span {
    background: blue;
    color: white;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

This will let the click event bubble straight down to the container.

Comment: didn't know about this property, thanks. anyway, as said in comments, the markup could change and I'd prefer a solution that allows me to change it without editing the css

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned get the target element and then traverse through the `.parentNode`

Not all browsers support target/toElement, so I use the following polyfill when getting the  target element:

```
var target = e.toElement || e.relatedTarget || e.target || function () { throw "Failed to attach an event target!"; }
```

Where e is the event

Comment: Which browser uses `toElement`? I only know about `srcElement` and `target`. Which browser uses `relatedTarget` for `target`?